# Error : Databinding with Android Studio 3.0 Beta 6

Tags: java, android, android-studio, data-binding

I have applied databinding to a project which was working fine in Android Studio 2.3.3 and just as I configured it for Android Studio 3.0 Beta 6 it stopped working.

It can not find any databinding package. I have put some base class for databinding in library module, can this be an issue? Please check proguard files also.

**NOTE** : I have already tried most questions & answers given in SO so please don't mark this as duplicate

**NOTE** : there is no errors at the bottom as suggested in comments. As I already told project was working successfully in Android Studio 2.3.3

**Project build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta6'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        google()
    }
}

project.ext {
    APPLICATION_ID = "com.packagename"
    BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION = "26.0.1"

    COMPILE_SDK_VERSION = 26
    TARGET_SDK_VERSION = 26
    MIN_SDK_VERSION = 19

    VERSION_CODE = 1
    VERSION_NAME = "1.0"

    SUPPORT_LIB_VERSION = "26.1.0"
    RETROFIT_VERSION = "2.3.0"
    GOOGLE_VERSION = "11.2.2"
    GLIDE_VERSION = "3.7.0"
    DATA_BINDING_VERSION = "1.3.3"

    MINIFY_ENABLE = false
    SHRINK_RESOURCES = false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**app module build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion COMPILE_SDK_VERSION
    buildToolsVersion BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion MIN_SDK_VERSION
        targetSdkVersion TARGET_SDK_VERSION

        versionCode VERSION_CODE
        versionName VERSION_NAME
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled MINIFY_ENABLE
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
def supportLibVersion = SUPPORT_LIB_VERSION
def retrofitVersion = RETROFIT_VERSION
def googleVersion = GOOGLE_VERSION
def glideVersion = GLIDE_VERSION
def dataBindingVersion = DATA_BINDING_VERSION
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibVersion"

    implementation "com.android.databinding:library:$dataBindingVersion"
    implementation "com.android.databinding:adapters:$dataBindingVersion"

    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$googleVersion") {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }

    //Retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:$retrofitVersion"

    //OkHttp Interceptor
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.0'

    //RxJava
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.1'

    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glideVersion"
}
```

**support module build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion COMPILE_SDK_VERSION
    buildToolsVersion BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion MIN_SDK_VERSION
        targetSdkVersion TARGET_SDK_VERSION

        versionCode VERSION_CODE
        versionName VERSION_NAME
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled MINIFY_ENABLE
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
def supportLibVersion = SUPPORT_LIB_VERSION
def retrofitVersion = RETROFIT_VERSION
def googleVersion = GOOGLE_VERSION
def glideVersion = GLIDE_VERSION
def dataBindingVersion = DATA_BINDING_VERSION
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibVersion"

    implementation "com.android.databinding:library:$dataBindingVersion"
    implementation "com.android.databinding:adapters:$dataBindingVersion"

    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$googleVersion") {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }

    //Retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:$retrofitVersion"

    //OkHttp Interceptor
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.0'

    //RxJava
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.1'

    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glideVersion"
}
```

**support module proguard:**

```
-keep class com.support.** { *; }

#Retrofit Start
# Platform calls Class.forName on types which do not exist on Android to determine platform.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
# Platform used when running on RoboVM on iOS. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform$IOS$MainThreadExecutor
# Platform used when running on Java 8 VMs. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
#if using @Header or @Query
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}

#GSON
-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.inject.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-keep class javax.inject.** { *; }
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }
-keepclassmembernames interface * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}
-keep interface retrofit.** { *;}
-keep interface com.squareup.** { *; }
-dontwarn rx.**
-dontwarn retrofit.**

#retrofit models
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }
-keep class com.support.retrofit.model.** { *; }

-keepattributes InnerClasses
-keepattributes Deprecated
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
# Retain generic type information for use by reflection by converters and adapters.
-keepattributes Signature
# Retain declared checked exceptions for use by a Proxy instance.
-keepattributes Exceptions
#Retrofit End

-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception

#Fabric
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**

#Glide
-dontwarn java.nio.file.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.**

#Glide Module
-keep class com.bumptech.glide.GeneratedAppGlideModuleImpl
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.AppGlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}
-keep class com.bumptech.glide.integration.okhttp3.OkHttpGlideModule

#Support Library
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }

#DataBinding
-dontwarn android.databinding.**
-keep class android.databinding.** { *; }
-keep class <com.support>.databinding.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}
```

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Please do not downvote without thinking, add a comment for why you are doing the same

Comment: these are the only errors? Generally with databinding, the actual error is at very bottom. Scroll to the bottom of errors & post it here. Also you don't need to add anything any dependencies in gradle for databinding. just enabling it is enough.

Comment: @sam_0829 yes I know that, there are no errors at bottom. gradle just can not find the databinding package. I firstly didn't add dependencies, but somewhere on SO they suggested to add them for new studio.

Comment: I also have this issue and couldn't resolve it. Consider to go back to AS 2.3

Comment: don't know how but this got resolved with Android Studio 3.0 beta7 update. But a new error came, which requires a new question so can not put it here